# Tried to run any artisan command and got an exception

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-artisan, php-8

After the project setup tried to run the `artisan serve` command and got the following exception:

```
In PackageManifest.php line 130:
                                                                         
  Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Collection::mapWithKeys()
```

I tried to run the Laravel server locally

UPD:

laravel.log

```
[2022-12-31 10:46:59] laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger. Using emergency logger. {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::flatMap() at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php:252)
[stacktrace]
#0 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(210): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->createStackDriver()
#1 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(125): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->resolve()
#2 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(112): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->get()
#3 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogManager.php(590): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->driver()
#4 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(252): Illuminate\\Log\\LogManager->error()
#5 app/Exceptions/Handler.php(53): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report()
#6 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(366): App\\Exceptions\\Handler->report()
#7 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(131): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->reportException()
#8 artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#9 {main}
"} 
[2022-12-31 10:46:59] laravel.ERROR: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Collection::mapWithKeys() {"exception":"[object] (Error(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::mapWithKeys() at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php:130)
[stacktrace]
#0 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(106): Illuminate\\Foundation\\PackageManifest->build()
#1 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(89): Illuminate\\Foundation\\PackageManifest->getManifest()
#2 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php(78): Illuminate\\Foundation\\PackageManifest->config()
#3 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/RegisterFacades.php(26): Illuminate\\Foundation\\PackageManifest->aliases()
#4 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(237): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\RegisterFacades->bootstrap()
#5 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(310): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith()
#6 vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(127): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#7 artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#8 {main}
"}
```

PackageManifest.php

```
$this->write(collect($packages)->mapWithKeys(function ($package) {
        return [$this->format($package['name']) => $package['extra']['laravel'] ?? []];
    })->each(function ($configuration) use (&$ignore) {
        $ignore = array_merge($ignore, $configuration['dont-discover'] ?? []);
    })->reject(function ($configuration, $package) use ($ignore, $ignoreAll) {
        return $ignoreAll || in_array($package, $ignore);
    })->filter()->all());
```

Comment: When you get an error in Laravel, go to your storage/logs/laravel.log and copy/paste that last error here, in your original question

Comment: is `PackageManifest` a model? add the line 130 of the this  file to your question

Comment: @zohrehda no, its one of Laravel files - `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/PackageManifest.php`

Comment: Deal with this one first: `laravel.EMERGENCY: Unable to create configured logger`, maybe some permissions issues, are you using Linux? Docker? Then ... go to `app/Exceptions/Handler.php(53)` and `dd()` the exception, you also have `$e->getMessage()`, dd() that as well. It's not finding a part from Laravel, which is weird AND it cannot write a log file, which is also weird

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

1. Deleted project
2. Cloned from repo again
3. Removed not available package
4. Ran `composer update`
5. Ran `php artisan serve` and it worked